# XMLHttpRequest vs curl doesn't work

Tags: javascript, c#, php, curl

today i'm triying make a little xhr in javascript, java, and c# but it doesn't work.... i dont know why

Here is the code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function init(){
    xhr.open("POST","http://www.opsu.gob.ve/portal/controles/ctrl_portal_cpnev_csni.php",false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie","SERVERID=webserver4");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin","http://www.opsu.gob.ve");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language","es-419,es;q=0.8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","*/*");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control","max-age=0");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection","keep-alive");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Referer","http://www.opsu.gob.ve/portal/principal.html?ir=cpnev_csni&tp=1&ci=24522469");
xhr.send("ci=24522469&tipo=1");
console.log(xhr.responseText);
}

init();
```

it just stay it and don't anything.... (I try with async true and the same thing happen)

but in curl... it works

Here is the line in curl

```
curl "http://www.opsu.gob.ve/portal/controles/ctrl_portal_cpnev_csni.php" -H "Cookie: SERVERID=webserver4" -H "Origin: http://www.opsu.gob.ve" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Referer: http://www.opsu.gob.ve/portal/principal.html?ir=cpnev_csni&tp=1&ci=24522469" --data "ci=24522469&tipo=1" --compressed
```

it should return that

5334143;-;2010;-;RICARDO;-;ALEJANDRO;-;MARCANO;-;QUINTANA;-;24522469;-;

but don't (with curl it does that)

what's wrong in my code?

you know any way to do that in c#, java or javascript?

why i don't use curl? well i try to get all the users registered there and it's over than 5.000.000 and do that with curl is very complicated....

I apreciate your help...

Comment: Your responseText will only be available when the call returns, so you'll have to wrap the console log into a `xhr.onload = function() {}`. Have a look at any ajax tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHTTP can't be synchronous, change the last parameter of the open to true.

As this, when your console.log is executed, the request isn't done this, to overcome this you need to set a callback with onreadystatechange, eg:

```
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText)
            }
        }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: what happen if the response are gzip compressed? how i uncompress the response?